# Regex to identify assignment to method name

Tags: regex, vb.net

Trying to build a regex that will find all assignments to function names when no return types is included.

So far I have created this regex,

```
(?s)Function(?:(?!End Function).)*?A =.*?End Function
```

and the part I am not familiar with is how to avoid hardcoding `A` with the found next word from the Function.

Regex engine is Visual studio's search, so .net.

```
//match
Function A() As Integer   
   A = 3
End Function

//do not match
Function Β() As Integer
   A = 3
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may capture the name using `(\w+)` and then backreference to this whole word using `\b\1\b`:

```
(?s)Function\s+(\w+)\b(?:(?!(?:End )?Function).)*?\b\1\b\s*=.*?End Function
            ^^^^^^^^^^                            ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ig2Utz/4)

**Details**

- `\s+(\w+)\b` - 1 or more whitespaces followed with Capturing group 1 matching one or more word chars, followed with a word boundary
- `\b\1\b` - `\1` is the same text as captured into Group 1 as a whole word (since it is enclosed with word boundaries).

You may read [more about *backreferences* here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).